# Java - why is "007F" printing out?

Tags: java, system.out

The following code is meant to decrypt based on `ASCII` values the "secret" `message :mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy`

What it should print out: "Attack at dawn!"

**What it *currently* prints out: "Attack 007F at 007F dawn?"**

So basically, right now `x = "007F"` and 
`y = "?"`

I need `x = SPACE` or " ", and `y = "!"`

Thanks for your time.

```
public class decryption
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String secretMessage = ":mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy";
        System.out.println(decryption(secretMessage, 88));
    }//end main

    public static String decryption(String s, int n)
    {
        int originalChar, decryptedChar;
        String message = "";
        char c;

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
        {
            c = s.charAt(i);
            decryptedChar = (int)c;
            if(decryptedChar + n > 126)
               originalChar = 32 + ((decryptedChar + n) - 113);
                  else
                     {originalChar = decryptedChar + n;
                     c = c;}
            message = message + (char)originalChar;
        }//end for loop
        return message;
    }//end method
 }//end class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that the ASCII values > 126 were incorrect so a simple subtraction of 95 fixed the decyrption!

```html
public class decryption
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 String secretMessage = ":mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy";
 System.out.println(decryption(secretMessage, 88));
}//end main

public static String decryption(String s, int n)
{
 int originalChar, decryptedChar;
 String message = "";
 char c;

 for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
 {
  c = s.charAt(i);
  decryptedChar = (int)c;
  if(decryptedChar + n > 126)
     originalChar = 32 + ((decryptedChar + n) - 113);
       else
     {originalChar = decryptedChar + n;
     c = c;}
      if (originalChar > 126)
      originalChar = originalChar - 95;
  message = message + (char)originalChar;
 }//end for loop
 return message;
}//end method
}//end class
```

Comment: Check if there is an unsigned-signed conversion when casting types using `(char)originalChar`.